# How to reallocate memory anyhow, even if realloc() failed in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

After a **successful allocation using malloc()**, sometimes the program needs to increase the size of the array. Though malloc() worked successfully, but **realloc()** failed.

I've used this piece of code to handle the failure of realloc().
Here **T** is the template parameter. **array** is a pointer of type T, **_size** is the total index of the array has been already used, **_maxSize** is the maximum number of usable index.
*Reallocation is needed when _size reaches _maxSize*.

```
if(_size == _maxSize){
    _maxSize *= 2;
    T *temp;
    temp = (T *) realloc( array, sizeof( T ) * (_maxSize) ) ;
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("...reallocation of memory failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        array = temp;
    }
}
```

Although the failure of realloc() was handled, **the program really needs to increase the array size** and I don't really know about how to perform the reallocation even if realloc() failed.

Comment: C or C++? The answer is different!

Comment: this code is written in c++ @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: IMHO, if `realloc()` failed the mission is nearly lost. That application might have a huge requirement of memory or the available memory might be very limited. (Is this an embedded system?) Either you have to look for memory leaks in your application or this application really needs much memory. In the latter case, I would think about to split data (read from file?) to process it in portions.

Comment: This is not really C++, but C code! Please update your question!

Comment: Do you think the allocator refuses to allocate out of spite, and there's a hidden memory stash somewhere that you can reach through other means than `realloc`?

Comment: "*Here **T** is the template parameter*" - so the code is C++, even though it is using a very C-ish way of allocating memory

Comment: Note (not related to the question): _If_ this is `c++` and `T` is a template type then you must be very careful to manually call its placement constructor / destructor in the right times - you dont supply all the code so we canht verify you're doing this. Infact using `realloc` doesn't even give you the chance to get this right - it can and will move memory sometimes and you wont get a chance to call the destructors. You _simply_ dont want to do it this way - it will only work in a limited number of scenarios and is simply too dangerous.

Comment: "How to reallocate memory anyhow, even if realloc() failed" You don't. In all probability, you can't.

Answer (score 6):

> ### How to reallocate memory anyhow, even if realloc() failed in c++

**In genuine C++, you never use `malloc` or `realloc`**, just [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) (which is implemented in your [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) implementation, and will call `malloc` internally!) and [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) (it usually calls `free`), and preferably [standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). Out of memory conditions are handled by exceptions (such as [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)) and you could [`catch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) these exceptions.

**In C, the robust solution would be to not use `realloc` and just use `malloc`, `calloc`, and `free`** (with `memset` to clear the area, and `memcpy` to copy it).

The real issue is how to cleverly handle out-of-memory conditions. This is a design issue, and is application specific. Be aware of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and **[garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) techniques, concepts**, and terminology. Observe that [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) is a primitive, but often used in C++, garbage collection technique. So read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/) or at least the [tracing garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection) wikipage for the *concepts* it will teach you.

Be aware of [memory over-commitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment). It is an OS feature that I dislike.

Be also aware that `malloc` and `free` (implemented in your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementation) are using operating system primitives (usually [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)). So read more about OSes, e.g. [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/). On Linux, these OS primitives are (very often) [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [munmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Because system calls are costly, your standard library will try to avoid them, and prefer marking `free`-d memory zones as reusable in future `malloc`-s.

Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). You would prefer developing your C++ code on some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) just to have `valgrind`. My opinion is that Linux provides a very developer-friendly software environment, so I recommend Linux for most programmers and students. Don't forget to compile with `g++ -Wall -g` (maybe also `-O2`, when benchmarking) and use when needed the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

More generally, read http://norvig.com/21-days.html - it gives a wonderful insight.